# What's wrong with the way I'm using setInterval()?

Tags: javascript

I want to print a paragraph containing a term that changes dynamically every second using the JavaScript setInterval method.

The changing terms are in an array that I want to iterate over. The problem is that instead of iterating over each term in the array and displaying it, only the last term in the array is displayed.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #changingText{
                color: blue;
                font-size: 2.8em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello! I am a <span id="changingText">person</span></p>

        <script>
            var changingText = document.getElementById('changingText');

            var things = ['Rap fan', 'runner', 'male', 'basketball player', 'mammal'];

            setInterval(changeText, 1000);

            function changeText() {
                for(var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
                    changingText.innerHTML = things[i];
                }

            }


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: every second the whole `changeText()` is executed. So each time you proint all the `things` one after another.

Comment: Has your question been answered?  If so do you mind accepting the answer you used so others don't waste their time. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: My question has been answered and I commented on the first answer that worked just fine.

Comment: @Adrian Customarily on Stack Overflow, if an answer works for you, it's best to click the gray checkmark to the left of the answer to officially mark it as "accepted". This gives reputation points to both you and the answering user, and tells other users that the question has been answered sufficiently. Thanks!

Comment: OK. Thanks for explaining that to me. I'm still very new to this site and its ways. I appreciate anyone who shows me the ropes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You for-loop runs within the `changeText` callback. Every second it is called and changes the text to all `things` which happens so fast that only the last item is seen.

The correct approach would be to keep track of the "current" element to display and update it every time the callback is invoked.

You could do this by storing the array index of the current element and increment it on every invocation. Make sure to take care of the array bounds.

```
var i = 0;
function changeText() {
  changingText.innerHTML = things[i];
  i = (i+1) % things.length;  // "wrap around" the index when array bound is reached
}
```

You could get rid of the counter alltogether:

```
function changeText() {
  changingText.innerHTML = things[0];  // always take currently first item
  things.push(things.shift());  // rotate items in array (put first to back)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your for-loop is looping over every member of the array **every time** your interval is called. What we want instead is for it to just increment `i`, display the result, and then exit the functon until the interval is called again.

Here's a working **Live Demo**:

```js
var changingText = document.getElementById('changingText');

var things = ['Rap fan', 'runner', 'male', 'basketball player', 'mammal'];

setInterval(changeText, 1000);

var i = 0;

function changeText() {
  changingText.innerHTML = things[i];
  i++;
  if (i >= things.length) i = 0;
}
```

```css
#changingText {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 2.8em;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello! I am a <span id="changingText">person</span></p>
```

Comment: One problem, when the index goes beyond the length of the array, trying to solve this here.

Comment: @AdamAzad Already ahead of you. Edited to use bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

The changing text function runs every second, the for loop runs every time from zero to length and then sets the last item as the text. You should extract the i variable and increment by one every time the function is called. Check if it is out of bounds then make it zero..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shortened and working code

```js
            var changingText = document.getElementById('changingText')
              ,things = ['Rap fan', 'runner', 'male', 'basketball player', 'mammal'];

            var i=0;
            setInterval(function(){
              
              if(things.length > i){
              changingText.innerHTML = things[i];
              i++;
              } 
            }, 1000);
```

```html
<p>Hello! I am a <span id="changingText">person</span></p>
```